# How to replace text with respect to its capitalization?

Tags: bash, awk

Here is the text in text.txt:

"**word1 Word2 word3**"

Now, I would like to have this output:

"**nword1 Nword2 nword3**"

What I have done so far:

```
sed -e  s/word1/nword1/gI text.txt
sed -e  s/word2/nword2/gI text.txt
sed -e  s/word3/nword3/gI text.txt
```

The thing is I do not know which word have a capital letter. So I have to input "sed -e  s/**word3**/**nword3**/gI text.txt" in lower case.

So basically, I would like to replace words with respect to capitalization of the original text. How can I do this in bash script?

Answer (score 1):

Perl

```
perl -CSDA -plE 'BEGIN{$f=shift@ARGV;$t=lc(shift@ARGV)}s/(?i)\b($f)\b/$1=~m!^\p{Upper}!?ucfirst $t:$t/xge;' word nword
```

The solution, not only prepending `N` to the `word`, but can convert any given word to another one, preserving the original word capitalization.

more readable

```
perl -CSDA -plE '
   BEGIN{ $f = shift @ARGV; $t = lc(shift @ARGV) }
   s/ (?i) \b($f)\b/ $1 =~ m!^\p{Upper}! ? ucfirst $t : $t /xge;
' word nword
```

But recommending to you create a `bash function` let say call it `casesubs`

```
casesubs() {
    #usage: casesubs fromword toword
    perl -CSDA -plE 'BEGIN{$f=shift@ARGV;$t=lc(shift@ARGV)}s/(?i)\b($f)\b/$1=~m!^\p{Upper}!?ucfirst $t:$t/xge;' "$1" "$2"
}
```

and you can now easily use it as the following examples:

```
(
    text='abcword word Word word wordlen';
    echo "$text"
    casesubs word nword <<<"$text"

) | column -t #pretty printing

abcword  word   Word   word   wordlen  #orig
abcword  nword  Nword  nword  wordlen  #changed
```

the solution works with any utf8 encoded Unicode, e.g. not only `[a-z]`.

```
(
    text='überJägermeister ÜBERJÄGERMEISTER'
    echo "$text"
    casesubs überJägermeister unterPIÑACOLÁDA <<<"$text"
) | column -t
```

output

```
überJägermeister  ÜBERJÄGERMEISTER
unterpiñacoláda   Unterpiñacoláda
```

and ofcourse with files too, e.g. having a file `capfile.txt` with a content

```
Ut debitis eveniet molestiae iusto quis ut. Est nemo dolores
error ipsum aut überJägermeister ÜBERJÄGERMEISTER. Numquam
itaque molestias ut iusto. Quia ut nobis expedita.
```

can use

```
casesubs überJägermeister unterPIÑACOLÁDA < capfile.txt
```

and get

```
Ut debitis eveniet molestiae iusto quis ut. Est nemo dolores
error ipsum aut unterpiñacoláda Unterpiñacoláda. Numquam
itaque molestias ut iusto. Quia ut nobis expedita.
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we could use simple bash:

```
replace=n

while read -r -a words
do
    out=()
    for word in "${words[@]}"
    do
        first=${word:0:1}

        if [[ "${first,}" == "${word:0:1}" ]]
        then
            word="$replace$word"
        else
            word="${replace^}${word,,}"
        fi
        out+=("$word")
    done
    echo "${out[*]}"
done<input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<NR; i++) { if ($i ~ /^[[:lower:]]/) {$i = "n"$i} else {$i = "N"$i}}}i' file
```

For your test case, it outputs:

```
nword1 NWord2 nword3
```

It will work irrespective of how many words you have on each line.

Comment: string, field, and array indices start at 1 in awk, not 0. When you do `substr($i,0,1)` you only get the result you expect because awk treats any invalid index, including `0`, as if it were `1`. The correct syntax is `substr($i, 1, 1)`. In any case, `match(substr($i, 0, 1), /[a-z]/)` can be written without the 2 function calls as just `$i ~ /^[a-z]/`. Also, `[a-z]` will match some upper case characters in locales where the sequence of letters is, for example, `aAbBcC...zZ`. instead of `abc..zABC...Z`. Better to use `[[:lower:]]`. Note that your output `NWord2` doesn't match the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`AWK` solution:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s%s"FS,($i~/\<[[:lower:]]/)?"n":"N",tolower($i);}}' text.txt
```

The output:

```
nword1 Nword2 nword3
```

*Explanation*:

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through all fields/columns(i.e. words)

`$i~/\<[[:lower:]]/` - checks if a field/word starts with lowercase letter.
 
`\<` is `gawk` regex operator which matches the empty string at the beginning of a word. For example, `/\<away/` matches ‘`away`’ but not ‘`stowaway`’.

`tolower($i)` - converts a word into lowercase

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk -v f="n" '
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        sub(/^./, ((c=substr($i,1,1))~/[[:upper:]]/?toupper(f):f) tolower(c),$i)
} 1' file
```

Of course you can pipe from the `echo` to the script as well. Explained:

- `awk -v f="n"` char to prepend is brought in a variable
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` iterate thru every word in record
- `sub(/^./, (` replace first char of word with
- `(c=substr($i,1,1))~/[[:upper:]]/?toupper(f):f) tolower(c),` first char of word is stored to `c` var and if it is a capital, produce capitalized char from `f` and lowered char from `c`
- `$i)` on every word

**Edit** As commened but untested.

Comment: @EdMorton I did not know that. Which locale would be such?

Comment: @EdMorton nvm, found a source.

Answer (score 0):

With what you've shown us for sample input, all you need is:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=($i ~ /^[[:upper:]]/ ? "N" : "n") tolower($i)} 1' file
nword1 Nword2 nword3
```

If that's NOT all you need then edit your question to show sample input that better represents your real data.

Answer (score -1):

i'll outline informal what you could do IMHO:

1. Read text file #1 into a variable, say textfile1

   In a for loop:

   2. Read text file #2 line by line, split at space into two variables pattern_to_match and replacement
   3. Find pattern_to_match in textfile1 (with case insensitive search) and store this in a variable, say match
   4. Find out if first character of match is lower or upper case and remember this in variable upperCase
   5. Capitalize the variable replacement if upperCase is true
   6. Replace in textfile1 pattern_to_match by replacement

**This can all be done in Bash/Sh.**

Comment: Why the down vote? The algorithmic description seems not too bad.